# Laravel5 app, How to store parent and 'one to many' child objects

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In my Laravel5 app, I have a one to many relationship, a service (name, description, begins, ends) that is offered with 'one to many' schedules (day, begins, ends).

Service.php:

```
class Service extends Model
{
    //

    protected $fillable = [

        'name', 'description', 'begins', 'ends', 'service_schedules'

    ];

    public function service_schedules()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ServiceSchedule');
    }
}
```

ServiceSchedule.php:

```
class ServiceSchedule extends Model
{
    //

    protected $fillable = [

        'day', 'begins', 'ends', 'service_id'

    ];
}
```

I use the form below to collect input for service/schedules creation. The vue2 code allows me to add/remove rows of fields for each schedule.

form.blade.php:

```
<div id="app">
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <br/>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Name<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    {!! Form::text('name', null, array('placeholder' => 'Name','class' => 'form-control')) !!}
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="description" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Description<span
                            style="color:red">*</span></label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    {!! Form::textarea('description', null, array('placeholder' => 'Description','class' => 'form-control')) !!}
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="begins" class="col-sm-2 control-label">From<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    {!! Form::date('begins', \Carbon\Carbon::now(), array('placeholder' => 'Begins','class' => 'form-control')) !!}
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="ends" class="col-sm-2 control-label">To<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    {!! Form::date('ends', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->addMonths(9), array('placeholder' => 'Ends','class' => 'form-control')) !!}
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="description" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Schedules<span
                            style="color:red">*</span></label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">Day</th>
                            <th scope="col">Start</th>
                            <th scope="col">Finish</th>
                            <th scope="col">Actions</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr v-for="(n, index) in rows" v-bind:id="index + 1">
                            <td>
                                <select class="form-control" v-model="n.day" v-bind:id="'service_schedules[' + index + '][day]'">
                                    <option value="1">Monday</option>
                                    <option value="2">Tuesday</option>
                                    <option value="3">Wednesday</option>
                                    <option value="4">Thursday</option>
                                    <option value="5">Friday</option>
                                    <option value="6">Saturday</option>
                                    <option value="7">Sunday</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                            <td><input class="form-control" type="time" v-model="n.start" v-bind:id="'service_schedules[' + index + '][begins]'" /></td>
                            <td><input class="form-control" type="time" v-model="n.finish" v-bind:id="'service_schedules[' + index + '][ends]'" /></td>
                            <td>
                                <button type="button" name="add-schedule" id="add-schedule" class="btn btn-link"
                                        v-on:click="addRow(index)"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-1x"></i></button>
                                <button type="button" name="remove-schedule" id="remove-schedule" class="btn btn-link"
                                        v-on:click="removeRow(index)"><i class="fa fa-minus fa-1x"></i></button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>

                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
```

My ServiceController currently stores successfully a new Service based on the form input. ServiceController.php store:

```
public function store(Request $request)

    {

        request()->validate([

            'name' => 'required|min:2',

            'description' => 'required',

            'begins' => 'required|date',

            'ends' => 'required|date|after:start_date'

        ]);

        Service::create($request->all());

        return redirect()->route('services.index')

                        ->with('success','Service created successfully');

    }
```

As I'm new to Laravel, I don't know how I should modify this code in order to also save the new schedules associated with a service based on the form input. Could someone please advise? Alternatively, could someone refer me to any similar example I can use as a guide?

Answer (score 0):

I see a few issues and I'll also highlight a few improvements.

```
class Service extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = [

        'name', 'description', 'begins', 'ends', // [1]

    ];

    public function serviceSchedules() // [2]
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ServiceSchedule::class); // [3]
    }
}
```

[1] First you should not include any relationships in `$fillable`

[2] Although not required you should try to follow [PSR/2 styleguide](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/). Laravel is smart enough to be able to convert the method name into a the underscore version (which I assume is your database table name)

[3] Use `ServiceSchedule::class` to avoid misspelling the relation name

To create a new model instance and and the same time relate it to its parent is really easy in Laravel:

```
$service->serviceSchedules()->create($request->all());
```

When you invoke the relationship as a function `()` it will return not the schedules but a query builder. This builder knows all about the relation already so all you have to do is run `create()` which takes a plain array as input. If you instead have a `ServiceSchedule` instance already you can use `save()` instead of `create()`.

Anyway in all cases it will set `service_id` on all the schedule instances for you.

Let me know if I need to clarify anything.

Comment: Thank you. Still not clear though on how to save the schedules. 1. Are the IDs of the schedule fields given in the form, suitable for Laravel to populate Schedule objects for saving? 2. In my code I don't have a $service object, only using Service::create, so how do I save Schedules linked to the created service?

Comment: When using Laravel models you don't have to care about ids. The above code will create all the ids needed.